# Line break represented as "\r" on Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, char, escaping

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkuwchop/): if you press `Enter` in the textarea on a recent Mac, the `newline` character appears to be represented by `\r`, which would be in direct contrast to the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824621/is-a-new-line-n-or-r-n) and [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n) and to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). To summarise these links:

- `\r` represents a line break on old Macs (OS 9 and before)
- `\n` represents a line break on UNIX systems (OS X, Linux)
- `\r\n` represents a line break on Windows.

When I press Enter in the JSFiddle, I get the following result (OS X 10.11.6):

```
textarea: \r

span: \n
```

This behaviour took a long time to figure out and seems illogical. What could be the underlying rationale?

Comment: your fiddle looks at the wrong thing, try testing the `.value` of the textarea...

Comment: Fwiw https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349214/enter-key-is-different-from-carriage-return-cr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you're confusing two things:

1. What character code does pressing the enter key yield?
2. What line ending is used on which platforms?

As far as I know, the answer to #1 is 13 (ASCII carriage return, "\r") for all platforms.

Do you have a platform where this is *not* what you're seeing?