# Add white-space before start of each line and except very first line of string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, webforms

I want to add a white-space before the start of each line and except the first line of string. I am using

input:

```
abc
def
efg
hij
```

output:

```
abc
 def
 efg
 hij
```

My code:

```
string text = "abc\ndef\nhij";

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text
                      .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                      .Select(line => " " + line));

TextArea1_trim_id.InnerText = result;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `Environment.NewLine`, if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Escape(Environment.NewLine))
```

you will notice it is `\r\n` or `\r` (Windows or Mac) but you expect only `\n`. Also, you could avoid the last `Select` by adding space during the `Join`.

```
string result = string.Join("\n ", text
    .Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

---

**n.b.** Look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824621/is-a-new-line-n-or-r-n).

Comment: thanks it is adding white-space before start of each line except very first line of string, but this code is adding a blank line between every two lines as well. What I want is It should only add space before start of each line and shouldn't add blank line after each line. I tried removing ''\n" `Split(new string[] { "" }, StringSplitOptions.None))`. but it is not working

Comment: I've solved this problem.  I've just replaced  `StringSplitOptions.None` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and `Environment.NewLine` with `" "` now it is working fine.