# Save UITextView String With \n Instead of Line Breaks (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my Swift app in which users can input text. They can input text with as many line breaks as they like but I need to save the string with the newline command (`\n`). How would I do this?

For example, my user inputs

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

in the `UITextView`. If I was to retrieve the string...

```
let string = textview.text!
```

this would return

```
"Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"
```

when I would like for it to return

```
"Line1\nLine2\nLine3"
```

How would I go about doing this? Can I use a form of `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`? I feel like I'm missing a fairly obvious solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! After WAY too much research and learning all about `String` escapes, I found a very simple solution. I'm quite surprised that this isn't an answer out there already (as far as I can tell haha) so hopefully, this helps someone!

It's actually quite simple and this will work of any `String` you could be using.

```
textView.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")
```

**Explanation**:
Ok so as you can tell, it's quite simple. We want to replace the newline command `\n` with the string `"\n"`. The problem is that if we replace `\n` with `\n`, it's just going to transfer over to a newline, not a string. This is why escapes are so important. As you can see, I am replacing `\n` with `\\n`. By adding an extra `\` we escape the command `\n` entirely which turns it into a string.

I hope this helps someone! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing \r with \n? or even \r\n with \n?

I hope I am not making an obvious assumption you considered, but maybe this may come in handy:
[Is a new line = \n OR \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824621/is-a-new-line-n-or-r-n)

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. Sadly, I have already tried this but to no avail. Thanks anyways, though!